# PDOStatement::rowCount() returning number of rows then 0 in one call

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I work with a MySQL DB and want to check if my `UPDATE` request works correctly.

To do so, after I executed my request, I want to return "true" to be able to redirect the user if the request was a success (in my Controller). It returns false by default.

```
if ($pdoStatement->rowCount() > 0) {
   // Updated album id
   $this->id = $pdo->lastInsertId();

  return true;
}
```

But even if the `UPDATE` worked (checked on my DB and on my website), I still not enter this condition. So I guess it means my `rowCount()` returns 0, which is weird if the request worked.

Here's my full function if needed :

```
    public function update() {
        $pdo = Database::getPDO();
        $sql = "UPDATE `album`
            SET
            title = :title,
            description = :description,
            picture_preview = :picture_preview,
            album_visibility = :album_visibility,
            last_updated = :last_updated
            WHERE id = :id";

        $pdoStatement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $pdoStatement->execute([
            ':title' => $this->title,
            ':description' => $this->description,
            ':picture_preview' => $this->picture_preview,
            ':album_visibility' => $this->album_visibility,
            ':last_updated' => $this->last_updated,
            ':id' => $this->id
        ]);

        // Checking the update
        if ($pdoStatement->rowCount() > 0) {
            // Updated album id
            $this->id = $pdo->lastInsertId();

            return true;
        }
        
        return false;
    }
```

I tried to dump my $pdoStatement->rowCount() and get two lines for a single dump (which confuses me) : the first one display "1", that is correct, but the second one display "0" just after. I guess it somehow overwrites the result of the request, but I don't get why, since I execute only one `UPDATE` request. Does it do a `SELECT` request for any reason after my `UPDATE`, so my last `rowCount()` is set to 0 ?

I also tried to set the option `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS` to `true` in my PDO object but the result is the same :

```
$this->dbh = new PDO(
                "mysql:host={$configData['DB_HOST']};dbname={$configData['DB_NAME']};charset=utf8",
                $configData['DB_USERNAME'],
                $configData['DB_PASSWORD'],
                array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING,
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS => true)
            );
```

Thanks in advance, I'm new to PHP, SQL and to Stackoverflow so I hope the question is fine

Comment: Does your update actually change some values in the row? If not the `rowCount()` will be zero because the row wasn't affected. `execute()` will return a boolean, if it is `true` then the update was successful even if nothing changed.

Comment: Yes, it does. I even tried to change every values to be sure, and they're actually updated in my database (and on the browser).
Edit : Should I try to check if the `execute()` returns `true` instead of using `rowCount()` then ?

Comment: lastinserid on a update statement?

Comment: The `lastInsertId()` was meant to send the id back to the Controller to double check it, but I'll probably delete it later. I tried without and still meet my `rowCount()` problem though

Comment: Yes, the boolean that `execute()` returns tells you exactly what you want to know: _"Was my update successfully executed?"_.

Comment: It actually works when I use `if ($pdoStatement->execute())` instead of `if ($pdoStatement->rowCount() > 0)`. Thank you !